# Weird issue with PhoneGap 2.2, predictive text and input type="text" on Android 4.0.3

Tags: android, cordova

I'm experiencing a weird problem with predictive text in PhoneGap 2.2 and Android 4.0.3 (on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7.0, the problem does not occur on other devices/Android versions). When predictive text is enabled on the device and I type text in any  input field no text is being added to the input field, and when a tap on a prediction a weird text is added to the input box. For example if I type "demo" no letters are being added to the input box, if I then tap on the prediction "demo" the string "d " (always the first letter of the prediction followed by a space) is being added to the input field. Does anybody know how what is causing this behavior? and how I can fix this?

Comment: Can you please post code?

Comment: there is no code to post. it's just an input text. I get the same issue, did you find some tricks to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it using the softKeyboard plugin. 
https://github.com/phonostar/PhoneGap-SoftKeyboard/tree/7eae2991eef34d4451968876c8b8893e309456e5

```
$(document).on({
        blur : function(){
            cordova.plugins.SoftKeyboard.hide();
        },
        focus : function(){
            cordova.plugins.SoftKeyboard.show();
        }
    }, ':input[type="text"],[type="number"],[type="email"]');
```